# Ada: protected objects deadlock

Tags: concurrency, ada

Let's suppose I have the following code in Ada:

test.ads

```
        package Test is

       type Gate; --forward declaration for mutual use

       protected type Foo is
          entry Do_Something;
          procedure UnlockGate;

          procedure Initialize(child : access Gate; me : access Foo);
       private
          Can_Do_Something : Boolean := True;
          Child_Gate : access Gate;
       end Foo;

       protected type Gate is
          entry Try_To_Do_Something;
          procedure Unlock;

          procedure SetParentFoo(parent : access Foo);
       private
          unlocked : Boolean := False;
          Parent_Foo : access Foo;
       end Gate;

       task Foo_User;

   task Gate_User;
   task Init;

   foo_inst : access Foo;
   gate_inst : access Gate;
end Test;
```

test.adb

```
    with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Test is

   protected body Foo is
      entry Do_Something when Can_Do_Something is
      begin
         --Do something
         null;
      end Do_Something;

      procedure UnlockGate is
      begin
         Child_Gate.Unlock;
         --Foo_User freezes here. It will make the call to Child_Gate.Unlock but just after that it will stop
      end UnlockGate;

      procedure Initialize(child : access Gate; me : access Foo) is
      begin
         Child_Gate := child;
         Child_Gate.SetParentFoo(me);
      end Initialize;
   end Foo;

   protected body Gate is
      entry Try_To_Do_Something when unlocked is
         pragma Warnings(Off);
      begin
         --Gate_User freezes here, it enters the procedure but will not make the Do_Something call
         Parent_Foo.Do_Something;
      end Try_To_Do_Something;

      procedure Unlock is
      begin
         unlocked := True;
      end Unlock;

      procedure SetParentFoo(parent : access Foo) is
      begin
         Parent_Foo := parent;
      end SetParentFoo;
   end Gate;

   task body Init is

   begin
      foo_inst := new Foo;
      gate_inst := new Gate;
      foo_inst.Initialize(gate_inst, foo_inst);
   end Init;

   task body Gate_User is
   begin
      delay 1.0;
      Put_Line("Gate_User is trying to do something");
      gate_inst.Try_To_Do_Something;
      Put_Line("This statement will never be reached, Gate_User task freezes...");
   end Gate_User;

   task body Foo_User is
   begin 
      delay 2.0;
      Put_Line("Foo_User is unlocking the gate");
      foo_inst.UnlockGate;
      Put_Line("This statement will never be reached, Foo_User task freezes...");
   end Foo_User;

end Test;
```

main.adb

```
with Test; use Test; --This will start the tasks

procedure main is
   begin
      null; --Nothing to do here
end main;
```

Let me explain what is happening here.
`Gate` and `Foo` "know" each other. `Gate`'s `Try_To_Do_Something` entry acts as a "gateway" to `Foo`'s `Do_Something` procedure. `Try_To_Do_Something` is locked by default, but a call to `Foo`'s `UnlockGate` will unlock it and allow all waiting calls to go through and call `Do_Something`.

This behavior may look weird, but this is just a sample to reproduce the problem. In the real program I have a multitude of gates and the `UnlockGate` procedure opens some and closes others depending on its parameters. Basically a series of `Gate`s is used to mediate access to the `Do_Something` procedure, depending on the internal state of `Foo`.

The comments in the code show where the `Gate_User` and `Task_User` tasks freeze.

What I don't understand is why. The problem is that `Foo_User` stops just after having called `Child_Gate.Unlock` and never returns from `UnlockGate`. Why is it stopping in the middle of a call? There aren't even any more statements in the call, why isn't it returning? Of course the `Do_Something` call that `Gate_User` is trying to make doesn't go through because `Foo_User` is still "inside" the protected call to `UnlockGate`, which I understand, but what I don't get is why that `UnlockGate` call doesn't return. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm using GNAT 2014 on Kubuntu 14.04 to compile and run this.
EDIT 2: Just done further testing. **This only happens on Linux! On windows it executes correctly.**
EDIT 3: Result of pstack:

```
31779: ./main
(No symbols found in )
(No symbols found in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
(No symbols found in /lib/ld-linux.so.2)
crawl: Input/output error
Error tracing through process 31779
```

Comment: You don't say anything about your compiler/OS, which may be relevant here. Did you use a debugger to verify that the tasks block, or are you relying only on the Text_IO output? In any case, Can_Do_Something is uninitialized, and may easily be False, explaining why the Do_Something entry blocks.

Comment: Sorry, edited the code, Can_Do_Something is true. In fact, the Do_Something guard is not influent from the tests I've done, even if it's always true the entry doesn't get called. Also edited question with environment info, I'm useing GNAT 2014 on Kubuntu Linux

Comment: OK, did you verify with a debugger? Are you running your program from inside GPS? What's the CPU usage of your program when it freezes?

Comment: Just done more tests. It only happens on linux! On windows it doesn't! From GPS or terminal it doesn't change. Trying using the GPS debugger now, will report back.

Comment: Since you're on Linux; instead of the debugger, you can do a "pstack <PID>" which will give a nice textual output of the stack traces that can be copy/pasted here

Comment: @egilhh : I'm not familiar with pstack, I pasted the result I get in the original post... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: pstack is a shell script that uses gdb to attach itself to a process and invoke "thread apply all backtrace" on it. I haven't seen the message you got before

Comment: @egilhh : yeah, I'm not having much luck searching for that kind of output on google.. mmm. By the way, forgot to answer you: cpu usage remains idle, so the tasks are not spinning/looping, they are suspended/blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've looked into this more closely (after realizing that `Can_Do_Something` is always `true`) and I think I've figured out the real cause of the problem.

RM 9.5.1(3) discusses the semantics of a protected subprogram call:

> If the call is an internal call (see 9.5), the body of the subprogram is executed as for a normal subprogram call. If the call is an external call, then the body of the subprogram is executed as part of a new protected action on the target protected object...

An external call is basically one that uses an object, as opposed to a protected subprogram in a protected body merely calling another subprogram in the same body, which is an internal call.  What the above quote means is that if a protected subprogram in `PObj1` calls a protected subprogram in `PObj2`, which then calls a protected subprogram in `PObj1`, you will get deadlock.  Whoever called the first subprogram started a protected action on `PObj1`.  When `PObj2` then tries to call a subprogram in `PObj1`, this is an external call and thus it tries to start a new protected action, which it cannot do since there is still a protected action taking place on `PObj1`.  The consequence of this is that your code, which relies on two protected objects calling each other as part of the same protected action, isn't going to work.  (It could be a compiler bug that the program works on Windows.)

In addition, your code is erroneous because a protected entry body (`Try_To_Do_Something`) is making a protected entry call (`Parent_Foo.Do_Something`).  A protected action should not call a potentially blocking operation (RM 9.5.1(8-16)), and an entry call is a potentially blocking operation.  The intended use of protected types is that "protected actions" should execute in a relatively small amount of time; they should not wait for anything.  So you shouldn't do that (even though, the way the code is now written, the entry call will never block).

RM 9.5.1 is [here](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-5-1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Due to the fact it worked on windows I never noticed this and I built an entire program with code similar to this as a crucial part. I know it should be redesigned from scratch, but for the sake of my sanity and sleep I have to ask: is there a "quick workaround" around this? Because the fact that I it works on windows (tested literally on thousands of runs) makes me think it might be a different compiler configuration between the win and lin version of GNAT... is this even remotely possible? Is there some compiler directive that might help me?

Comment: This bite me many years ago, complete with "but it runs in windows" :( No idea on how to make linux behave right now, but there's some pragma (Detect_locking maybe?) that will cause an exception instead of a silent deadlock, which might help in removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I've got it. This is what happens:

- `Gate_User` blocks on `Foo.Try_To_Do_Something` (waiting for unlocked)
- `Foo_User` calls `Foo.UnlockGate` and takes the Foo mutex.
- `Foo_User` calls `Gate.Unlock` and takes the Gate mutex.
- `Foo_User` set unlocked to `True`
- `Foo_User` (before releasing the Gate mutex) evaluates the barrier condition of `Try_To_Do_Something`.
- `Foo_User` calls `Try_To_Do_Something` as if it was `Gate_User`. (it is allowed to do this before it returns and releases the Gate mutex (and then the Foo mutex), as an optimization to reduce tasks switches, if a barrier condition becomes true and there are tasks in the queue for the entry)
- `Foo_User` blocks on `Foo.Do_Something` since it has already taken the Foo mutex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "Foo_User calls Try_To_Do_Something as if it was Gate_User" thing. What do you mean "it calls"? And if this is a compiler optimization, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

It's always erroneous to make a potentially blocking call from a protected body.  Maybe change to tasks, or use a monitor or semaphore (which can be implemented as a protected type) inside procedure calls?  I like the Booch 95 monitor and lock.